# XMPP App Engine service does not work with mobile Gtalk apps

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

I made a XMPP app engine application, it works on Gtalk client on desktop properly, however there is a problem with the mobile version of Gtalk that only the presence works however chat messages are not pushed to the server, I have tried to many mobile gtlak apps and still getting the same problem

Comment: When you say "messages are not pushed to the server" do you mean they're not received by the client, or do you mean messages the client sends aren't received by your app? When you say "Gtalk client on desktop," do you mean a native client like Pidgin or Adium, or chat-in-Gmail?

Comment: The messages are not received by the application, so the application can't respond at all. Also I am not sure that after this is fixed that the client (gtalk app) will receive the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your app is configure to receive messages, like so (it sounds like you've already got xmpp_presence)

If Python, make sure this is in app.yaml:

```
inbound_services:
- xmpp_message
- xmpp_presence
```

If Java, make sure this is in appengine-web.xml:

```
<inbound-services>
  <service>xmpp_message</service>
  <service>xmpp_presence</service>
</inbound-services>
```

Second, can you try sending to a client (manually subscribe to your bot) just on a normal request rather than responding to a message? This will let you test sending messages independent of receiving them.